# Declare Cell value given by formula as string

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I have a formula that displays a value in a cell, however I cannot declare the value of that cell as string in a VBA code as it's not a "real" value but a dynamic one based on the formula. How would I go about using the value as a string? Is there any way to convert a result given by a formula to string via VBA?

This is the formula in cell I1: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,REVIEWERS!A:C, 3, 0),"")`

I am trying to declare the value in I1 as string with the following code:

```
Public list As Worksheet
Public bsawt as worksheet
Sub BSAW_Export()
Dim ReviewerID As String

    Set list = Sheets("LIST")
    Set bsawt = Sheets("BSAW_TABLE")
    ReviewerID = list.Range("I1").Value

    lastrow = list.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastrow

        If bsawt.Range("E" & x).Value <> " error" Then bsawt.Range("F" & x).Value = ReviewerID

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your code will set `ReviewerID` to the Value not the formula of Cell `I1`. Also, you've declared the variable as a `String` so any value in that variable will be a `String`. So where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to use the `.Text` property instead

```
ReviewerID = list.Range("I1").Text
```

Comment: Nope the code runs properly, but it doesn't fill out the cells in bsawt column F

Comment: Are you sure this bsawt.Range("E" & x).Value <> " error" is working then? As .Text reads in a string from the cell.

Comment: Although I suppose there is some issue as none of the suggested solutions work even though they seem correct.

Comment: I have to assume that the problem is with  bsawt.Range("E" & x).Value <> " error"    or there is no value to assign as .Text will read in a string and as far as I know is the simplest way, hence the .Text property existing. Have you put a Debug.Print inside to check condition is met after the <> line ?

Comment: Okay figured it out, lastrow = list.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row was referring to the "LIST" sheet instead of the "BSAWT" sheet, so the loop didn't have any cells to cycle through. Otherwise your suggestion of using .Text worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `CStr`function? [CStr function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cstr.php)

```
Public list As Worksheet
Public bsawt As Worksheet
Sub BSAW_Export()

Dim ReviewerID As String

    Set list = Sheets("LIST")
    Set bsawt = Sheets("BSAW_TABLE")
    ReviewerID = CStr(list.Range("I1").Value)

    lastrow = list.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastrow

        If bsawt.Range("E" & x).Value <> " error" Then bsawt.Range("F" & x).Value = ReviewerID

    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without VBA**

The usual way to convert a formula's output to text is:

```
=TEXT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,REVIEWERS!A:C, 3, 0),""),"General")
```

If you have a specific text-format in mind like Date or Currency, then just replace the *"General"*

Comment: Thank you this one worked as well, but I used @QHarr's solution as it was simpler. Don't want to mess with the formulas as some colleagues might freak out hehe.